# Find all integer solutions to the following easy-looking Diophantine equations

Tags: nt.number-theory, polynomials, diophantine-equations

In general, it is not clear [What does it mean to solve an equation?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/410297) in integers. In this question, let us assume that an equation
$$
P(x_1,\dots,x_n)=0
$$
is solved if we have proved that its integer solution set $S \subset {\mathbb Z}^n$ can be represented as the finite union $S=S_1 \cup \dots \cup S_m$, where each $S_i$ is either a polynomial family or a family defined by recurrence relations. Here, $S \subset {\mathbb Z}^n$ is a polynomial family if there exists polynomials $P_1,\dots,P_n$ in some variables $u_1,\dots,u_k$ and integer coefficients such that $(x_1,\dots,x_n) \in S$ if and only if there exists integers $u_1,\dots,u_k$ such that $x_i=P_i(u_1,\dots,u_k)$ for $i=1,\dots,n$.

Following Zidane [What is the smallest unsolved diophantine equation?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/316708/) , let us define size $H$ of the equation $P=0$ as a result of substitution 2 instead of all variables, absolute values instead of all coefficients, and evaluating.

All equations with $H \leq 8$ are easy to solve. However, simple-looking equation $xy-zt=1$ with $H=9$ has been open for decades. In 2010, Vaserstein https://annals.math.princeton.edu/wp-content/uploads/annals-v171-n2-p07-s.pdf proved that

- The solution set to $xy-zt=1$ is a polynomial family with $46$ parameters.

As a corollary of this, Vaserstein solved the following families of equations

- $xy-zt=D$ for any integer $D$;
- $yz=x^2+D$ for any integer $D$;
- $x_1x_2+x_3x_4+Q(x_5,\dots,x_n)=D$ for quadratic form $Q$ and integer $D$.

In addition, the following equations/families has been solved:

- Equations in the form $dyz=ax^2+bx+c$ for integers $a,b,c,d$ has been solved in the answer to question [Polynomial parametrization of the solutions to $yz=x^2+x\pm 1$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/412451/)
- All equations with $H \leq 12$.

I was also able to solve all equations with $H=13$ except of the following ones.
$$
x^3 + 1 = yz
$$
$$
x^2y=z^2 \pm 1
$$
$$
x^2y=tz+1
$$
$$
x^2 + y^2 \pm 1 = zt
$$
$$
x^2 \pm 1 = yzt
$$
$$
x_1x_2x_3+x_4x_5=1
$$

For each of the listed equations, the **question** is to find all integer solutions. Specifically, check whether the set of all integer solutions is a finite union of polynomial families and/or families defined by recurrence relations. You do not need to write the resulting families explicitly, because, as example $xy-zt=1$ indicates, they may be quite complicated.

See here [Can you solve the listed smallest open Diophantine equations?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/400714) for a version of this question where we only want to check whether any integer solution exists, and here [On the smallest open Diophantine equations: beyond Hilbert's 10 problem](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/411958) for a version where we also check whether the solution set is finite or infinite (and find all solutions if there are finitely many).

Answer (score 0):

The equation $x^2+1 = yzt$ has a parametric solution as follows.

We factorize $x^2+1 = yzt$ in $\mathbb Z[i].$

Let $(Y,Z,T)=(a+bi,c+di,e+fi)$ then

$x+i = YZT = (acf+ead+ebc-bdf)i+ace-fad-fbc-bde.$

Hence we get a parametric solution $x = acf+ead+ebc-bdf$ if $ace-fad-fbc-bde =1.$

Comment: We are not allowed to use the "if" condition, otherwise there is a trivial answer $x=a$, $y=b$, $z=c$, $t=d$ if $a^2+1=bcd$. We can only use "if" condition if we know how to solve the equation under if statement. So we have reduced the problem of writing parametric solutions of $x^2+1=yzt$ to the problem of writing parametric solutions of $ace-fad-fbc-bde=1$. This equation does not look any easier for me than the original one.

Comment: This condition is necessary to obtain all integer solutions, just as we did for $yz=x^2+x+1$.

Comment: With $yz=x^2+x+1$ we used the condition $ab-cd=1$ which we were allowed to use only because this equation has been solved in the Vaserstein paper. He proved that $ab-cd=1$ if and only if $a=P(u)$, $b=Q(u)$, $c=R(u)$, $d=T(u)$ where $P,Q,S,T$ are some polynomials and $u$ is a vector of variables without any conditions.

Comment: Then is we have $x=ad+bc+bd$, $y=a^2+ab+b^2$, $z=c^2+cd+d^2$,  then $x=P(u)T(u)+Q(u)R(u)+Q(u)T(u)$, $y=P^2(u)+P(u)Q(u)+Q^2(u)$, $z=S^2(u)+S(u)T(u)+T^2(u)$ gives the final answer without any conditions on parameters $u$. This is not available for the condition $ace-fad-fbc-bde=1$. In general, we may use any condition defined by an equation that we have already solved (or that is solved in the literature).

Comment: Okay, I hope it will be parameterized.